# How to set a new path in request url in middleware (laravel)

Tags: laravel, http, request, middleware

I need your help. I have a middleware which set a locale to every url in web:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
    URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]); 

    return $next($request);
}
```

But I need one thing - set a new url (path e.g. /5-product-in-english) for the next request (I have old url, find a new url and I need it to rewrite). Which part of request handling this path?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do here and how can you make this assumption about the next request?

Comment: Did you try `redirect` instead of  `$next`?

Comment: I would like to go to the next request but I need to change URL in browser input.

For example: I have product in en lang with url https://www.web.com/en/5-product-chair. When I switch lang to DE in this middleware I change local (in URL) but I need path to https://www.web.com/de/5-product-stuhl
Route is: Route::get('product/{product}-{url}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.showen');